# JSViews - Render flat array data with html

Tags: jquery, jsrender, jsviews

I'm using JSViews and trying to pass to a template an array of strings, some of which will contain html. The template:

```
{^{for items}}
    <li> {{>#data}} </li>
{{/for}}
```

My JSON looks something like this:

`{
    "items": ["<b>Steak</b>", "Cheese"]
}`

Upon rendering it doesn't bold the word 'steak' but instead prints the `<b>` tag. I've tried swapping the `{{>#data}}` for `{{:#data}}` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `{{>}}` tag - which HTML encodes data. If you want the strings to be included in the HTML without HTML encoding, you need to use `{{:}}`.

In your case you can write `<li>{{:#data}}</li>` or simply `<li>{{:}}</li>`

See http://www.jsviews.com/#htmltag and http://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag.